# What is Couch DB? What is the process of search & retrieval of data from Couch DB?

Tags: database, oracle, couchdb

What is Couch DB? How is that different from conventional oracle DB? What is the process of search & retrieval of data from Couch DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/intro.html

Couch DB is a non-relational, schema-free database. Please visit the project's site to learn more - it would not do to copy-paste the content from there to here.

The two categories above are the main difference from usual SQL databases, which are both [relational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) (use schemas to define data) and have those schemas rigidly defined (you can not use ad-hoc data formats) for every possible data type/table.

We would be glad to answer *specific* questions you will have about CouchDB :)

Answer (score 0):

- Key-value pair type storage (NoSQL)
- [Document oriented storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database)
- Bottom line is it gives you schemaless database (semi-structured). Which is easily horizontally scalable
- There is no 1 database. It's a distributed storage system. There are various nodes which hold the data.
- Data available (querying) via a [Restful JSON Api](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/intro.html)
- Couchdb's real world example on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680408/couchdb-a-real-world-example)
- [Sample](http://sitr.us/2009/06/30/database-queries-the-couchdb-way.html) data store in CouchDb:

  { key: "Clarke", value: { last_name: "Clarke", first_name: "Kim" } }
- Read the 4 Features listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB#Features) and you will get the whole picture.

Though it's not exactly the same, but read [Amazon Dynamo](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html). It's interesting and similar.

**Update:**

One of the best reads about CouchDB for relational DB users: [A Gentle Introduction to CouchDB for Relational Practitioners](http://blog.couchone.com/post/1167966323/a-gentle-introduction-to-couchdb-for-relational)

Comment: CouchDB is not **per se** a distributed database and it does not have a lot in common with Dynamo. CouchDB's strong side is peer-based replication though which enables you to setup things like multi-master replication very easily.